# Removed apps and users, Android OS uses too much data

Tags: mobile-data, background-data

I've noticed that Removed apps and Users uses too much data on the background. But dont know the reason.

[image]

In this photo I can see that Removed apps and users, and Android OS uses too much data. How to reduce this usage?

[image]

I know that Removed apps and users are use by my uninstall apps, disabled apps in the session. But if I use the uninstall apps then why this photo shows the the data used in foreground not in background .? Then how to reduce usage of Removed apps and users,  and Android OS

Comment: looks like normal youtube data to me. if the apps are uninstalled how can they use data (how can you know it)? if apps not uninstalled, enable it, check the usage again (and see the apps names)

Comment: I believe it's showing the history of removed apps and users' data usage. Did you uninstall some apps this month? For Android OS, related question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40446/44325, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/140155/44325, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/195368/44325

Comment: Ok I have uninstall some app but Didn't disable app. But see the 2nd photo it shows that the Removed apps and users uses data on the background. Do you know what is background. It allow a app to use data without opening the app

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew T. is right. This is showing the history. To see today's data usage you will have to select the range as `Todays date` -  `Same date one month later` from the dropdown menu 
The range of one month is default

I know this question is old but just to remove it from the "Unanswered Questions Section"